# Tkinter GUI: How do I Insert a selected option from a dropdown menu in an Entry box

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing some code in Python which includes the `OptionMenu` widget. I would like to create an `OptionMenu` that calls a function when the option is changed. The function will then insert that selection in an entry box. This is what I have so far, however I get this error

> TypeError: show() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

this is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter

root = Tk()
root.title('example')

root.geometry("500x400")

plan = Entry(
    bd = 0,
    bg = "#d9d9d9",
    highlightthickness = 0,
    font='halvetica 12')
plan.insert(tkinter.END, "")
plan.pack()

clicked = StringVar()
clicked.set('Plans')
days = ["mon", 'Tue', "WED", "thur"]

def show():
    plan.delete(0, END)
    plan.insert(tkinter.END, clicked.get())

drop = OptionMenu(root, clicked,*days,  command=show)
drop.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: So the error message states that `def show()` need to take one parameter so give it one and change it to **`def show(e)`**:

Comment: The `e` in **`def show(e)`** is a string with the in the menu clicked text, so you can use **`e`** instead of `clicked.get()`

Answer (score 1):

The `command=` keyword argument is used to assign a callback function to a `OptionMenu` which will automatically be called with the option the user selected as an argument.

You're getting the `TypeError` because your `show()` function is defined as not taking any arguments. Also, because the selection is being passed as an argument, there's really no need for the `clicked.get()` call you have in the `show()` function.

Below is your code with the modifications need to avoid the problem:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter

root = Tk()
root.title('example')

root.geometry("500x400")

plan = Entry(
    bd = 0,
    bg = "#d9d9d9",
    highlightthickness = 0,
    font='halvetica 12')

plan.insert(tkinter.END, "")
plan.pack()

clicked = StringVar(value='Plans')
days = ["mon", 'Tue', "WED", "thur"]

def show(choice):
    plan.delete(0, END)
    plan.insert(tkinter.END, choice)

drop = OptionMenu(root, clicked,*days, command=show)
drop.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

##### Simpler Approach

You really don't need to use a `OptionMenu` callback function to do what you want because it can be made to happen *automatically* by specifying the same `StringVar` as both the the `OptionMenu` variable *and* as the `textvariable=` option of the `Entry` widget. Here's some `[documentation][1]` on the topic and below is your code modified to take advantage of it:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter

root = Tk()
root.title('example')

root.geometry("500x400")

clicked = StringVar(value='Plans')
plan = Entry(
    textvariable=clicked,  # <-- ADDED
    bd = 0,
    bg = "#d9d9d9",
    highlightthickness = 0,
    font='halvetica 12')

plan.insert(tkinter.END, "")
plan.pack()

days = ["mon", 'Tue', "WED", "thur"]

#drop = OptionMenu(root, clicked, *days, command=show)
drop = OptionMenu(root, clicked, *days)  # <-- NO CALLBACK NEEDED
drop.pack()

root.mainloop()
```